# Is it possible to use a Smartphone audio jack as MIDI output?

Tags: audio, midi, smartphones, trs

Is it possible to use a Smartphone audio jack as MIDI output?

My plan is to use a standard TRS to MIDI cable, like the one Arturias Beatstep uses, to connect a Smartphone/Tablet to a MIDI device.

I want to make a step-sequencing software that uses as simple of a connection as possible.

As far as I've read, MIDI needs to hold 5V, and I'm not sure if that's even possible to do.

I also don't know about AC or DC. I'm assuming though that MIDI is using DC, while the audio output uses AC? I might be wrong on that, but that would completely negate my plan in any case.

For devices that use USB-C, I don't know if I can do something with that. Probably only with audio as well, but might have the same problems as the TRS version.

Comment: My piano outputs MIDI through a USB port. But you talking about TRS makes it seem like there is a more physically raw form of MIDI rather than one that goes to the PC.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes MIDI interfaces were simple UART comms over optoisolated 5mA current loop using DIN connectors, and existed some 15 years before USB and how to transport MIDI over USB was invented. What might trigger this question is that due to devices getting smaller it has recently been officially allowed to transport MIDI over TRS plug if the DIN connector is too big.

Comment: @DKNguyen the original MIDI physical interface that Justme references is sometimes still preferred because its opto-isolation can help eliminate audio signal ground loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it *possible*?  Yes, but **not** with a simple cable that connects a 3.5mm TRS to a MIDI DIN connector.  I'm not familiar with the Arturias Beatstep, but your question suggests that it uses something like this.  (Justme's comment on your question suggests that that some other manufacturers take this approach to save physical space for the connector.)

You would need:

- Real-time software control of the smartphone audio output sufficient to send a modulated version of the MIDI data out of the audio jack. (I don't know enough about the smartphone software ecosystem to say whether the OS will allow this.)
- Some kind of *powered* (could be a battery) electronic interface circuit to demodulate your signal and turn it back into a MIDI bit-stream.
- Driver circuitry something like the Sparkfun article referenced in Transistor's answer to send the data to a MIDI jack.

If you're going to go to that trouble, you might as well figure out how to send MIDI over Bluetooth and build a MIDI Bluetooth "dongle" in a DIN plug shell.

For USB-C, there are already off-the-shelf products to interface to standard MIDI.

Comment: Yes its indeed used by different manufacturs to safe some space on small devices. And i know that its not an audio output by any means, just uses the same connection piece:

What you are saying would be basicly the solution B i had in mind, converting the signal to be send out and then converting it back to MIDI via additional hardware.

According to my programmer buddy, it isnt a problem to control the audio port, so that could work.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use headset audio output for MIDI output.

The TRS connector on smartphone is meant to be connected to headsets, it has no circuitry that is compatible with MIDI.

MIDI interface is an opto-isolated 5mA current loop, and currently it is allowed to be used with 5V and 3.3V supply voltages. Traditionally a 5-pin DIN connector is used, but these days also a TSR connector can be used for the same signals as devices have gotten smaller and portable.

So even if some devices use the same TSR connector for MIDI than what smartphones use for headsets, it does not make the devices compatible just because they use the same connector.

The Arturia BeatStep uses a standard MIDI output interface, but with a 3.5mm TRS connector, and thus it needs an adapter to provide a MIDI output with a standard DIN connector. The 3.5mm TRS port on the Arturia BeatStep is still a MIDI port, while the 3.5mm TRS port on smartphone is still a headset port.

Comment: Yes, i know its different types of connectivity, even if its the same connector.
Thats why i was aksing here, if the audio jack could produce what MIDI needs.
But i learned now that it pyhsically cant, so the only way would be a conversion.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use a Smartphone audio jack as MIDI output?

No.

> As far as I've read, MIDI needs to hold 5V, and I'm not sure if that's even possible to do.

[image]

*Figure 1. A MIDI interface between two devices. Image source (and further information): [Sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/midi-tutorial/hardware--electronic-implementation).*

There are many, many articles on the web and probably on YouTube that explain that the MIDI interface drives an LED opto-isolator in the receiver. This is generally done by switching a 5 V supply with a logic driver. The resultant signal is an on/off current through the receiver's opto-LED.

> I also don't know about AC or DC. I'm assuming though that MIDI is using DC, while the audio output uses AC?

Yes, MIDI is switched DC. Audio is AC.

Comment: Really useful information there, thanks!